# How can i push notification on my web app

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to add a push notification system on my web app.

Example:

- one user is clicking on the button of one website. a second user is
- notified about the click like a push notification

I tried a lot of things: Notification push with services workers but I am stuck when it is necessary to use his own server because there is only me who can be notified with my Key.

Please help!

Comment: Hi, You can use chrome notification functionality to do this.

Comment: You can use `OneSignal` https://onesignal.com/

Comment: If you have control over the server then you may implement server push functionality over websockets.

Comment: You could use [Notifications API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API) together with [socket.io](https://socket.io/)

Comment: Thanks, i will try the Notifications API

Answer (score 1):

One way I would recommend is to use [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/).

It has APIs and well written document. It is easy to get it to work too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried it but OneSignal 
allows you to send notifications based on time and not according to an action on my application. Maybe there is an issue..